# single page web app and authentication

Tags: php, authentication, dart, angular-dart

Here's the set up, I want to build a single page web app, Dart and Angular dart are my front end tools.

For server back end I'm using PHP with a view of it being only the CDN for the web app and a REST api for data to serve this web app.

I need to build in some log in and authentication and I've settled on Openid to make sign up and login as easy as possible.
I've spent the last few days combing the net and this forum for a solution that makes sense and now I'm only more confused :)

I can get basic auth info on both client side and server side using 'log in with "X"' examples, that authenticates the user and I can create/register them server side, all cool there.

My question now is how do I use this info in the most secure and efficient way between the web app and the server?
Here are my thoughts/options:

1. Do I just create a session on the server and when the web app makes ajax calls for data check they are still logged in before replying?
2. For true RESTful api's I understand it's better to verify on each call, how to do that from the ajax call from the client? Do I pass something (i.e. a token) to the client at log in to send on each call and how would I do this?
3. Do I do this the other way around and get the auth details client side and pass them server side for verification somehow before sending data?

I'm primarily a desktop developer so this is all a bit overwhelming at the moment, any advice as to which way I should proceed would be greatly appreciated.
A simple step by step process description to give me some direction would be great, thanks.

Mick.

Comment: What you had tried so far with you code ?

Comment: Hi Sulthan, I'm still in preliminary design stages and need more guidance than code help.
It's more of a login auth flow that I need to understand.
Thanks for your interest.
Mick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a one solution (I'm not an expert, but I'm thinking about to use this):

**A new hashed password is stored to database**

User creates a password and the new password is stored to database in hashed mode (with dart you can use at server-side for example this package: [password_hasher](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/password_hasher), there must be similar packages for php).

**Verify login and create session information with expiration time**

When user logins and gives a password, compare given password to stored one (use the functions from previous package). If passwords matches, then create a new entry to a database or create session cookie in server side. The new entry should have unique id and expiration time (for example 30 minutes). The id is sent back to the client. The client stores the id.

**Verify each request and renew the expiration time**

When the client makes a request, it also sends the id back to server. The server verifies the received id to the id entries in the database. If the ids match, the expiration time of the id in the database is renewed back to 30 minutes and the request is replied.

**User logs off or there is a long inactive time**

When user logs off, a logoff request with the id is sent to the server and server removes the id from the database. If there is an inactive time period of over 30 minutes, server removes the session id automatically.

**Unauthorized request**

If a request from the client doesn't include the session id or the id is not found from the database, server sends the client a reply with a request of redirection to login page or sends the login page (depends on how the application is build).

**The main security things are:**

1. Never store a password as a text
2. Don't send the hashed password around with every request, but use session related id for continuous transfers
3. Expire the session related id automatically
4. Redirect every unauthorized request to a public page

Comment: HI grohjy,
I was thinking along these lines also but using something from the openid login in the session.

The whole point of using openid for me is so I don't store passwords, the idea of sending a session 'token' or similar that a sniffer would most likely dismiss as nothing important is an option I'm thinking about.
This is created in a session on load then used throughout the session along with session id/info and also use auto log out and time limits as you suggest.
Would that be feasible and secure?
Thanks.

Comment: I think the important thing is to verify user at server end. It means you have to store some information about user to database in server (for example email-address) and then you can use suitable interfaces (OpenID, OAuth 2.0 or build your own) for verification. OpenID etc. reduces the number of passwords user must remember. Eavesdropping must be handled with https or similar, because with every login transaction there is some "secret" passed over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you create a session cookie on the server when the client is successfully authenticated. The client must send this session cookie with each request to the server.
I haven't used PHP myself but I'm sure there are ready-to-use packages available for PHP.
Security is tricky and easy to do wrong therefore you should not try to bake something yourself.
There shouldn't be anything to do on the client because the browser sends cookies back to the server with each request by default.

Comment: Hi Günter,
I understand this part ok, it's just after reading so much the past few days I'm wondering if that's enough or whether there's more to it.
I'm competent with php and am using a small lib to do openid auth that works fine so that part is covered server side.
Maybe I'm just overthinking it a bit, thanks again for you input.
Mick.

Comment: The same for session handling with the client. Look for a library, I'm sure there are several good out there for PHP too (expecially for PHP).